# Enthought Canopy: Where do os.environ variables come from?

Tags: python, environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion, enthought, canopy

I have the following problem. I wanted to use the matplotlib package animation to save an mp4 video file. The save function has a dependency for generating the mp4 file, the ffmpeg external library. So I installed ffmpeg on a Mac osx 10.8 via Macports, and it got installed in `/opt/local/bin` .

But now, running the script in canopy, the interpreter (ipython shell) can not see ffmpeg. I added the path to my .bash_profile, and I can run the program at my terminal, but when I type `os.environ['PATH']` the actual `PATH` of my shell was not added, and `/opt/local/bin` is not there. 
If I try to run the script, I get this error:

```
/Users/alejandrodelacallenegro/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-      packages/matplotlib/animation.py:695: UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
```

Any ideas to fix the problem? What I have to do to change an environmental variable that python sees at startup? Did anyone have the same problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here has nothing to do with Enthought; it's that OS X doesn't run bash when you launch things from Finder, LaunchDaemons, etc., and therefore doesn't access your `.bash_profile`. Instead, it runs them from `launchd`.

If you want to add some environment variables to affect anything run by `launchd` for the current user, that's easy:

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH:/opt/local/bin
```

---

If you want this to happen every time you log in, if you create a file `~/.launchd.conf`, the subcommands in that file will be run through `launchctl` every time `launchd` starts (which is the first step in logging in a new user session).

If you want it to be system-wide, rather than just for your user, you can `sudo` launchctl and/or create/edit `/etc/launchd.conf`. However, you almost certainly don't want to change the environment used by `root` services, etc., unless you really know what you're doing.

If it helps: Using `launchctl` manually, editing `~/.launchd.conf`, and editing `/etc/launchd.conf` are roughly equivalent to `export`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `/etc/profile` (except of course that they affect `launchd` rather than `bash`/`sh`).

See the [`launchctl(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) man page for details, or just type `launchctl` to start an interactive session and use the built-in help. (The pages `launchd(8)` and `launchd.conf(5)` also have useful info.)

You can also use the deprecated `environment.plist` file to affect even things that aren't run by `launchd`, but… that's deprecated, and there really isn't anything for it to affect that you care about, except in (much) older versions of OS X.

---

People coming from other Unix systems are often caught out by this. Most file managers ask the shell to run programs for them; Finder.app (and the command-line tool `open`, and the AppleScript environment, and so on) ask `launchd` to do it. Plus, on most X11 systems, if you look up the process tree from your file manager, it was ultimately launched by a user shell too, whereas on OS X, Finder.app was launched by `launchd`, which was launched by the system-wide `launchd`; no shell in sight.

This also means that other shell-specific stuff like changing resource limits or default umask won't affect programs started outside the shell on a Mac. `launchctl` is again the answer.

Comment: Great clear explanation, thanks. Linked to it in this article: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-

Comment: @JonathanMarch: Thanks. But I'm not sure I'd recommend editing `/etc/launchd.conf`, unless you want it to affect all users. Do you really want to modify the PATH used for services run by root? If not, just `edit ~/.launchd.conf` instead of `sudo edit /etc/launchd.conf`.

Comment: Actually, the `$HOME/.launchd.conf` is "currently unsupported", according to the man page of `launchd.conf`.